# Changing one material's properties affects other materials... and the relevant objects don't share mats. (maybe MMD_Tools-specific?)

Tags: materials, mmd-tools

[Blend plus relevant sphere images](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UpF_D05sXr7GIFcnhag3SCvEQNgSkPNn/view?usp=sharing). You may need the MMD_Tools plugin, as explained below, but it's essentially a materials issue.

I have here a character with a "fins/lens" material and a "scarf" material for the highlighted parts:

[image]

Why, when I change the (MMD_Tools) sphere property for "fins", does the same property also change for "scarf"? This even happens after I close and reopen Blender.

[image]

As you can see, the two objects don't share materials:

[image]

[image]

The aforementioned sphere property appears under MMD Texture in the following screenshot. Thus, it *could* be plugin-specific--and another plugin-specific field (MMD Material) also shows incorrect material colors despite the normal Surface settings displaying the correct ones--but has a similar glitch happened on non-MMD models too?

[image]

Comment: Hello, it's hard to say without diving into the add-on code, but there may be a callback on the color property that automatically updates color on multiple materials. I'm not familiar with the add-on but you can try to open an issue on the github to ask the developer about it. https://github.com/powroupi/blender_mmd_tools/issues

Comment: It could also modify a specific node group that can be shared by multiple materials, could you post a screenshot of the node tree of one of the materials ?

Comment: I've never used a nodes-based workflow. How do I retrieve the screenshot you want?